# How to allow user to type in a textbox and focus on a button

Tags: jquery, css

I have two textboxes and a button as follows:

My objective is that when the user is typing into `textbox ID` it must set a focus on the button.

What I tried:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '#ID', function () {
    $("#Btn").focus(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="10" id="code" name="code">
<input type="text" size="10" id="ID" name="ID"> 
<input type="button" value="choose" name="Btn" id="Btn">
```

Every time I type one letter in it switches the focus to the button, which it's doing what I'm telling it to.

But the question I have is how do I let the user type continuously into the textbox while the focus is set on the button? I do not want the button to be focused on page load, only when the user types into the `ID` textbox should focus be set on the button.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to focus the button?

Comment: its a styling requirement, i dont need it for a enter key

Comment: You can't - typing into a text field requires focus, you can't focus both elements at once. If it's just the styling you require, then add a class that gives the same style as :focus?

Comment: i only need it when the textbox is been typed in

Comment: Since you only need it for styling purpose, why not change the `css` that resembles your focus style instead?

Comment: if i set a focus on css for the button its going to show all the tiime,i only want it to show when the textbox has been typed in.

Comment: I meant programmatically add the class when the user types, in the same way as you're currently trying to add focus, i.e. instead of `$("#Btn").focus()` do `$("#Btn").addClass('focus')` and then have a .focus CSS style - as per 31piy's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the focus to button will prevent any interaction with the text box. So, an alternative solution will be something like the following:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '#ID', function() {
  $("#Btn").addClass('focused');
});
```

```css
.focused {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="10" id="code" name="code">
<input type="text" size="10" id="ID" name="ID">
<input type="button" value="choose" name="Btn" id="Btn">
```

You can assign a class, which resembles the focus, to the button when there is any keypress on the text box. Of course the CSS can further be tweaked so that your button looks like similar to when its not focused.

So, you need to work on the CSS a bit to give the button a consistent look and feel.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could target the button with [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) when `input[type="text"]` has focus

```css
input[type="text"]:focus ~ input[type="button"] {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="10" id="code" name="code">
<input type="text" size="10" id="ID" name="ID"> 
<input type="button" value="choose" name="Btn" id="Btn">
```